# ActiveRecord 6 without Rails: Connecting to multiple databases

Tags: ruby, activerecord, multiple-databases

I have a legacy codebase which I need to upgrade to ActiveRecord 6.  It does not use Rails.

I need to be able to connect to multiple databases.

In my code, I have:

```
conf = ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations.new({ 'test' => db_config })
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = conf
```

where `db_config` is defined as:

```
def db_config
  {
    'adapter'  => 'mysql2',
    'name'     => 'testdb',
    'host'     => xxx,
    'port'     => 3306,
    'username' => xxx,
    'password' => xxx,
    'database' => 'testdb'
  }
end
```

However, I am running into an error when I execute my unit tests in rspec:

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified:
  The `testdb` database is not configured for the `test` environment.

    Available databases configurations are:

    test
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I thought the fact that it shows a test configuration should mean that the database is configured for the test environment.  Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to database `testdb`, while the one you have is `test`. Try changing the config:

```
def db_config
  {
    'adapter'  => 'mysql2',
    'name'     => 'test', # was 'testdb`
    'host'     => xxx,
    'port'     => 3306,
    'username' => xxx,
    'password' => xxx,
    'database' => 'test' # was 'testdb`
  }
end
```